# JWT Authorize fails when specifying roles

Tags: c#, jwt, roles, .net-5, authorize

I'm creating a .net5 web api and want to use JWT as a way to auth users. I previously used JWT in dotnet core 2 and 3.1 so I mostly copied the code I used then.

For some reason I can't get it to work with `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`.
I got it working by explicitly stating `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` but this just feels wrong and means my config is wrong/lacking somewhere.

Here's the config code:

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey =
                        new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role
                };
            });
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var authBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                authBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .RequireAssertion(context=> context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Confirmed").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault() == "True");
                options.DefaultPolicy = authBuilder.Build();
            });

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;

            });
        }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you need Admin Priviledges?  VS doesn't run with as admin unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The code will run properly if you execute the exe compiled file but if you are running in VS you need to start VS using As Admin.